# Error while opening Visio doc from Sharepoint (Sharepoint Office interop issue)

Tags: c#, sharepoint-2010, office-interop, visio

I am trying to open a visio doc using the following bit of code
`_stencilDocument = _stencilApplication.Documents.OpenEx(visioFilePath,(short)VisOpenSaveArgs.visOpenHidden);`
Now this code works fine when its in an independent project , but shows `File not found/could not be opened` error when put in a user control and deployed to a SharePoint site.
I have checked the value being passed in `visioFilePath` (that is not the issue),
Could this be some permission issue of SharePoint?

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked your DLL's build target, it should be set to Any CPU. If set to X86 you will get these weird access denied errors..

Comment: Could you try and run the console app as the user the WebApplication's application pool is running under. (the webapp your control is supposed to run under). You can run an application by holding shift and the right the exe -> run as (different user).

Comment: there are no console apps, when i said an independent application I meant a web application that was not hosted on SharePoint